# How to get local snapshots of the CVS repository

Tags: svn, version-control, cvs, mirror

I need to set up some kind of read-only CVS repository mirror. The aim is to get snapshots of the project by schedule and store it on a windows box. Could you suggest best way to do it?

I don't actually have to use CVS on local. Our team works with Subversion. And if it possible to check out from CVS to SVN it would be even better. Because there is no need to commit any changes to the CVS repository. All I need is to have actual snapshots of sources from CVS.

Do I have to use migrating tools like cvs2svn with cron for windows to schedule it? Or are there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the cvs export command to get them. But i would suggest to do a migration via the already mentioned cvs2svn script.

Comment: Do I need to have an access to the CVS server for using cvs export?

In case of cvs2svn it needs at least python and Cygwin (or smth like that) installation. And I'm trying to find the solution with minimum of additional tools installed.
But it looks like cvs2svn will be the best solution in any case.

Comment: If you are using cvs2svn you need cvs access to the original repository as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. 
After all I've simply decided to use ant for exporting project from cvs and committing it into svn. All revision info is lost, but it allows me to do some necessary processing after checking out.

Comment: If its just for posterity and since you don't need an special scripts to migrated a CVS repository, a simple copy / zip of the server side repo works too if you don't want to deal with cvs2svn. This way you can always refer back to it when needed, and maintain your commit history.

Answer (score 0):

My best reco would be git cvsimport
Second best if it does not fail is cvsclone then cvsuck
The issue in each case might having incremental updates, it requires a bit more work.
But if the cvs repo is small enough, then doing a full clone each time with git cvsimport